# headless mode with autoit in virtual machine

Tags: python, headless

I try to work with AutoIt in vm and I try to do it in headless mode. AutoIt works only if rdp connects and I try to do headless mode. how can I do headless mode from OS or from code i call to exe autoit or change code in AutoIt.

I want the script AutoIt to run in headless mode. All the information I found on the Internet is only about the web-driver